# Prevent double-clicking on Button

Tags: asp.net-3.5, double-click

I keep having an issue with users double-clicking on action buttons on my web application, which is meaning duplicate records are being added into my database, and sometimes the user is being charged twice (as the action is being ran twice).

What is the best way of preventing double clicking in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're concerned about this in the face of users without javascript enabled. If that's the case, you need to deal with it on the server side. One idea to deal with this would be to implement [CSRF tokens](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) throughout your app.

This basically keeps a token in the server side session, and also requires the token to be submitted in the request. Provided youreset this token in the session in a timely manner (and assuming that you're using usual ASP.Net mechanisms to serialize access to the session), the second request will be using an out of date token, and can be ignored.

Comment: Cheers Damien. Is this the standard way to prevent double-clicking?

Comment: @Curt - I've not had to implement it many times. Since you say that it's sometimes resulting in double charging, I'd do what everyone else does in this situation - put a big, scary notice above the button that tells people "If you double click this, I might charge you multiple times" - i.e. don't try to write an IT solution for a people problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to disable button after clicking using Javascript. Try adding onclick function to it:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="disable_button(this);" />
<script type="text/javascript>
    function disable_button(sender){
        sender.disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

It can also be done using server-side code using server controls. Paste this into your pre-render or page_load event:

```
yourButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; "+ ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Button1,null)+";");
```

This will basically disable the Button when ever u click it and then calls the server side code as if the button has been clicked.

Comment: yes, thats right. Data is added to the database in the Button_Click event

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a little JavaScript to the submit button?

e.g.
`<input type="button" onClick="formSubmit.disabled=true;">`

This way the button is disabled right after the first click and won't take the second click ...

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't help for users without javascript. I didn't know if there was a standard way of preventing this? Seems like a simple mistake to make

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a session variable without enabling or disabling the button.
In the Page_Load add :

```
Session["clicked01"] = "0";
```

in the  btnSave_Click :

```
if (Session["clicked01"] == "1")
{
    return;
}
/// save the record
Session["clicked01"] == "1"
```